# React CSS Modules, babel-plugin-react-css-modules with electron-compile no webpack

Tags: electron, babeljs, react-css-modules, electron-forge, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I am trying to start using `react-css-modules` w/ [babel-plugin-react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules). At present I have an [electron-forge](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge) application running react.

My `.compilerc` looks like the following:

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "application/javascript": {
        "presets": [
          ["env", { "targets": { "electron": "2.0.0" } }],
          "es2015", "stage-0", "react"
        ],
        "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-runtime"],
        "sourceMaps": "inline"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "application/javascript": {
        "presets": [
          ["env", { "targets": { "electron": "2.0.0" } }],
          "es2015", "stage-0", "react"
        ],
        "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-runtime"],
        "sourceMaps": "none"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's my understanding that `.compilerc` is analogous to `.babelrc` (I do not have a `.babelrc` file), see: [electron-compile](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-compile#how-do-i-set-up-babel--less--whatever-the-way-i-want) (which electron-forge makes use of - I guess)

However, I have `.css` files in my project directory, and if I run `DEBUG=* electron-forge start` I see that the are just being passed through ( not preprocessed )

I have tried adding `react-css-modules` to my `plugins` line in `.compilerc` and *also* creating a new `.babelrc`

`.compilerc`:

```
 "env": {
        "development": {
          "application/javascript": {
            "presets": [
              ["env", { "targets": { "electron": "2.0.0" } }],
              "es2015", "stage-0", "react"
            ],
            "plugins": ["react-css-modules", "transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-runtime"],
            "sourceMaps": "inline"
          }
        },
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "application/javascript": {
        "plugins": ["react-css-modules"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Both of which after running `yarn add babel-plugin-react-css-modules -s`, but I still get a compilation error no compiler found when I attempt to run:

`import "mystyles.css"`